# Not able to get image on Facebook wall if image shared is from my website using Javscript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

**If i use the link of first image then the image appears on the Facebook share dialog. But if i use the link of second image(my website) no image appears on the Facebook share dialog.**

1)First Image - https://www.websolutions.com/Customer-Content/www/CMS/images/portfolio/evans/thumb-sq-300.jpg
2)Second Image - https://www.tardigradetech.in/resources/img/4.jpg

If i am using the code:

```
 FB.ui(
        {
          method: "share",
          href: ImageLink,
          description: "sdsdds sds",
          caption: "sdsdds sds"
        },
        function(response) {}
      );
```

- The version used in Fb.init({}) is v2.10.

I just want to share the image from my web page to Facebook. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Because there is something wrong with your SSL cert https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tardigradetech.in%2Fresources%2Fimg%2F4.jpg

Comment: Guessing it is chain issues https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.tardigradetech.in but you also have a bunch of other problems.

Comment: Yea.... Thanks a lot @WizKid